# Cannot find module '@shopify/dragable' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular

I am trying to import the Draggable module from @shopify/draggable package, but am getting an error on build :

Could not find a declaration file for module '@shopify/draggable'

Which is odd because I followed the docs for [import](https://github.com/Shopify/draggable/tree/6f5539b1f396a34b08fcbf0b52651ca1ee669665/src/Draggable) .

I've also found another [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axd7ac?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) which uses the Droppable import from @shopify/draggable where the editor shows an error but their code runs !

I'm at a loss what the problem with my import is, and I'm relatively new to Angular so this could be something simple. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you happen to have a typo there? it should be `@shopify/draggable` but the error says `dragable` with only one `g`...

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu . ah that fixes it on my demo but on my local project it still doesnt work . I've updated the post with the actual error .

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get this error is because you import a Javascript library and try to use it as a TypeScript library.

You can try to generate `.d.ts` files, but it is not a simple task.

Since you are new to Angular, I recommend that you check out [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/categories). It's a lot easy to work with since it's built to be used with Angular. The [Angular Material CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/categories) will have most of the features you need if you want to build more stuff on top of what they offer. This [Angular Material Drag-Drop CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it as a dep using `npm i @shopify/draggable` you'll likely have version 1.0.0.beta-8, which doesn't have type annotations. Try installing it using `npm i @shopify/draggable@next`, this will install the latest version (1.0.0.beta-12) that has typescript support.